# transfer file from windows machine to hortonworks sandbox HDFS

Tags: ssh, scp, connection-refused

I want to upload one file from a local windows machine to HDFS. I am using Hortonworks Sandbox for Hadoop.

I have tried the following command to transfer file, but it shows *connection refused.*

```
scp -p 22 SampleData_1.csv root@localhost:
scp -p 22 -r SampleData_1.csv root@localhost:
```

[Connection Refused.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8Qjd.jpg)

Comment: You can't use scp to copy over HDFS. Use httpfs/webhdfs to transfer files from a windows box